# How to filter the query_set by multi-params?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

How to filter the query_set by multi-params?

```
class UserListAPIView(ListAPIView):
    """
    return the user list
    """

    pagination_class = UserPageNumberPagination

    class Meta:
       ordering = ['-id']

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        return UserListSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):

        username = self.request.query_params.get("username")
        real_name = self.request.query_params.get("real_name")
        phone = self.request.query_params.get("phone")
        company_name = self.request.query_params.get("company_name")

        return User.objects.filter(
            is_admin=False,
            is_staff=False,
            is_superuser=False,

            username=username,
            real_name=real_name,
            phone=phone,
            company_name=company_name
            )  # if `username, real_name, phone, company_name` all are None, there gets `[]`
```

The serializer:

```
class UserListSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    """
    user list serializer
    """
    username = serializers.CharField(allow_null=True, allow_blank=True)
    real_name = serializers.CharField(allow_null=True, allow_blank=True)
    phone = serializers.CharField(allow_null=True, allow_blank=True)
    company_name = serializers.CharField(allow_null=True, allow_blank=True)
```

You see, my `username , real_name, phone, company_name` all are `allow_null`.

I want to query all the user that meet the conditions.

But gets `[]`, when I do not pass the `username, real_name, phone, company_name`.

I want to if the `username` is None, it do not filter the `username`, if `real_name` is None, it do not filter the `real_name`. (I means it do not filter out it)

I have a idea, but it is fit for less fields, if there is only one `username` field:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    username = self.request.query_params.get("username")
    if username == None or username == '':
        return User.objects.filter(
                is_admin=False,
                is_staff=False,
                is_superuser=False)
    else: 
        return User.objects.filter(
                is_admin=False,
                is_staff=False,
                is_superuser=False,
                username=username)
```

But there are so many fields, I can not write all judge conditions.
I tried use

```
    return User.objects.filter(
            is_admin=False,
            is_staff=False,
            is_superuser=False,

            username__contains=username,
            real_name__contains=real_name,
            phone__contains=phone,
            company_name__contains=company_name
            )
```

But do not work too.

Is there a good way to realize this requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a dict then pass it using keyword expansions.

```
filters = {'{}__contains'.format(key): value
           for key, value in query_params.items()
           if value is not None}
return User.objects.filter(**filters)
```

If there is a pagination parameter, it could be excluded with:

```
filters = {'{}__contains'.format(key): value
               for key, value in query_params.items()
               if value is not None and key != "page"}
```

Answer (score -1):

I hope this is what you are looking for.

```
from django.db.models import Q
obj_list = User.objects.filter(
                is_admin=False,
                is_staff=False,
                is_superuser=False,
                Q(username__contains=username)|
                Q(real_name__contains=real_name)|
                Q(phone__contains=phone) |
                Q(company_name__contains=company_name)
                )
return obj_list
```

let me know if this work for you.

Comment: The OP does not state he wants to `OR` the conditions.

Comment: should't the `|` be `&`?